# Can I please get the deleted comments made on this question?

Tags: support, status-declined, comments

Comments made on this question have been deleted: [Why did Lucas choose the word "Force"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76163/why-did-lucas-choose-the-word-force)

I want to get a deleted comment which was a scolding full of alien terms. Is this possible to get that?

**Update:**
I just got the comment I was looking for, thanks to @Randal'Thor (he consulted with a CM who said it was okay). It was (in case anyone is curious):

> Keep in mind that making up scifi terms is a VERY common trope, so be nice before the Sangheili and the Salarian Dalatrass hold an Entmoot about ending your time in the 'Verse with a bat'leth, you frackin' varool.

Comment: Why do you want it? You might want to trying flagging this for moderator attention. Or wait a while, this is a busy time for many!

Comment: @Wikis As I mentioned in the question, one comment was interesting. I just want to clip it.

Answer (score 10):

We don't resurrect comments unless there's a particularly compelling reason to do so, and "it was interesting" just isn't compelling.

Comment: I am not asking for resurrection... I just want contents. Just post here if you can see.

Comment: Apparently we ***do*** resurrect comments for no compelling reason.

Comment: @Valorum No comments have been undeleted on the question in question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Given that the OP has just posted the contents of that deleted comment, I beg to differ.